# How to restart flink job to use added TaskManager

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm testing the elasticity features in Flink 1.3.0. I have a job with checkpointing enabled and fixed-delay restart policy. When I kill one of the TaskManager JVM, after a while the job correctly restarts on the remaining node. However, when I add a new node, the job is not restarted automatically to make use of it.

I tried to use `bin/flink stop <jobId>` but it always gives me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job with ID <jobId> is not stoppable.`

How can I restart the job to make use of the additional node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flink 1.3 does not provide dynamic rescaling, and won't automatically restart a job to take advantage of newly available resources. To restart a job in such a scenario, you should take a savepoint, increase the parallelism, and restart the job from the savepoint. You can cancel a job with a savepoint like this:

```
flink cancel -s [targetDirectory] <jobID>
```

and then restart it via

```
flink run -s <savepointPath> ...
```

See the [CLI docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/cli.html#savepoints) and [savepoint docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/savepoints.html) for more details on savepoints, but you can think of a savepoint as a user-triggered checkpoint.

[Apache Flink® at MediaMath: Rescaling Stateful Applications in Production](https://data-artisans.com/blog/apache-flink-at-mediamath-rescaling-stateful-applications) is a recent blog post from data Artians with a lot of detail about how rescaling works internally.